# Custom picker with access to option value instead of just selected index

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a custom Picker that makes a custom value available to the parent (as opposed to just the selected index). In the example below, I've got a `@State` variable bound to `selection` on the picker as well as a computed variable `selectedOption` which updates correctly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomPicker: View {
    var options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"]

    @State var selectedIndex = 0

    var selectedOption {
        options[selectedIndex]
    }

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedIndex, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(0..<self.options.count) { index in
                Text("\(self.options[index])").tag(index)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

However, I want to be able to interact with the `CustomerPicker` in another view like this:

```
@State var selectedOption: string;

...

CustomPicker(selectedOption: $selectedOption)
```

So that the parent view is dealing with the option directly, as opposed to the index. Does anyone have any tips as to how I would go about this using SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom picker needs `@Binding` to the selected index. I think it would also be a good idea to offer a "no selection" option to the picker itself:

```
struct CustomPicker: View {

    var options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"]

    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int?

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedIndex,
               label: Text("")) {
            Text("no selection")
                .tag(Optional<Int>.none)
            ForEach(0..<self.options.count) { index in
                Text("\(self.options[index])")
                    .tag(index)
            }
        }   .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```